# Visual Studio 2017 OpenGL starts very slowly

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, visual-studio-2017

I'm new to learning OpenGL in fact I just started following along a great resource called "learningopengl", This resources teaches how to setup GLFW and GLAD to use OpenGL on visual studio 2017. However, I've noticed when running even just an extremely basic program that only builds a blank window, that can be resized (following along the learning material) it takes visual studio consistently 40 or so seconds to actually load the program. it runs fine once its up, it simply takes an annoyingly long time to open.

I know this isn't supposed to take so long because through my searching around and looking at videos of people using these same libs/includes when they run there sample programs they load up instantly.

I was hoping I could find out why this is the case. for reference the sample code I'm running is show below.

```
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW\glfw3.h>

#include <iostream>

void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height);

int main() {

    // glfw: initialize and configure
    // -----------------------------
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    // glfw window creation
    // --------------------
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "LearnOpenGL", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL) {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);

    // glad: load all openGL function pointers
    // ---------------------------------------
    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress)) {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // render loop
    // -----------
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        // glfw: swap buffers and poll IO events (keys pressed/released, mouse moved etc
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    // glfw: terminate, clearing all perviously allocated glfw recourses
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;

}

// glfw: whenever the window size is changed (by OS or user resize) this callback function executes
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height) {
    // make sure the viewport matches the new window dimensions; note that width and
    // height will be significantly larger then specified on retina displays.
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}
```

Just a finial clarification, I do not mean that any kind of frame rate is slow, I mean from the time I tell visual studio to run the project (Ctrl+f5 or run the debugger) to the time I can see the actual OpenGL window i'm trying to make takes approximately 40 seconds or more.

Also when I run the code a cmd prompt runs behind it I was also wondering why that happens and if there is a way to prevent it or if it happens because of a setting.

Comment: MSVC includes a profiler, a 40 delay should be fairly easy to spot.  Also just doing step-over in the debugger may be enough to find the problem.

Comment: When running project under debugger Visual Studio will look for debug information files (.pdb) for every loaded library, querying them from internet when necessary. If you see in output window a delay after each module loads then it is definitely a .pdb loading delay. Another possibility would be raging antivirus software. You should add your workspace with C++ projects into antivirus exceptions.